# Access to operation "function" was denied while calling a ria services from non silverlight project

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

After adding a service reference for a ria service(domain service) at windows application ,
i can't call any of theses domain service methods, and error appeared that acccess to operation "SaveChanges()" was denied.

client code:

```
                PromotionHeaderDSSoapClient client =
                new PromotionHeaderDSSoapClient();
                ChangeSetEntry[] Customer = new ChangeSetEntry[1];
                ChangeSetEntry csEntry = new ChangeSetEntry()
                {
                    Operation = DomainOperation.Insert,
                    Entity = newCustomer
                };
                Customer [0] = csEntry;
                client.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error and the code in which the error happens.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code; do not post the code in a comment.